# Multiple row text staying at bottom?

Tags: html, css

When The HTML COde is

```
<div class='wrap'>
<div class="blocks">div 1</div>
<div class="blocks">div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>
</div>
<div class="blocks">div 3</div>
<div class="blocks">div 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS is as follows

```
.blocks {
display:inline-block;
width: 25%;

.wrap {
    width:100%;
}
```

The resulting text of div 1 and div 3 align at the bottom of div2. Any idea?

Comment: Try `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` at the top of your CSS to make sure there is no inherent browser styling going on.

Comment: Also note that you're missing a closing `}` in your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The default styling for elements displayed inline (including images and `inline-block` elements) is to have `vertical-align: baseline;`.

This basically means that all of your elements are lined up with the [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) of the text in the text flow.

Try putting a `border` on your `<div>` elements to see what's going on. You can change `vertical-align` to `bottom` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code for the problem:

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrap'>
<div class="blocks">div 1</div>
<div class="blocks">div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>div 2
    <br>
</div>
<div class="blocks">div 3</div>
<div class="blocks">div 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.blocks {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.wrap {
    width:100%
}

.wrap:after {
  clear: both
}
```

**RESULT**
[image: RESULT]

[SEE CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/fbLyi)

A few things to note:
-It is the default behavior the the browsers to put the container that has less `height` at the bottom position relative to the container that has the maximum height. This can be aided by using `float: left`. It tells the browser to render the element by "hanging" it to the top left.

-Oh, don't forget to use `clear:both` for the container that has `float: left` child elements to clear out this "hanging" render behavior.

-Use `reset.css` to get rid of those unnecessary default behavior of the browser. In this example, I use

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

-Notice the `box-sizing: border-box`, this will help you defining the container properly when you add `padding` properties to your containers.

-Have fun playing around :D